# How to get the geographic location using IP Address in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, geolocation, ip

I know that this code:

```
string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
```

will give me the IP Address of the user but I don't know how to get the location of the user

I want to know the location and related information on basis of IP Address.

Comment: What you're looking for is called "geolocation".  A Google search for something like "HTML geolocation" yields a lot of results, for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation  Conversely, if you're looking to geolocate a given IP address, you might try something like "geocoding" for which there are a number of APIs, for example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185508/IP-Address-to-Geolocation here is the what you need

Comment: Note: IP Address is usually enough to narrow a user down to a particular country, but much more than that is fuzzy. An IP Address location will resolve to the ISP node it's belongs to, which *may* be a particular city if it's a big one, like New York, but in more suburban or rural areas may only resolve to the state the user is in or even just a region like midwest U.S. To clarify, what I'm talking about is resolution to the user's actual location. You'll get full city, state, etc., but that's for the *node* not the user.

Comment: Also VPN and proxy services can mask the user's true IP, and hence their location. A U.S. user could present as one from China if they use a Chinese proxy. In other words, don't rely on this information for anything important. If you need the user's location for a real purpose, ask them for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should help you - http://freegeoip.net/

freegeoip.net is a public REST API for searching geolocation of IP addresses and host names.
Send HTTP GET requests to: freegeoip.net/{format}/{ip_or_hostname}.  The API supports both HTTP and HTTPS and Supported formats are csv, xml or json.

Answer (score 4):

Model to bind the user location details

```
public class IpInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("ip")]
    public string Ip { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("region_name")]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country_name")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time_zone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }      
}
```

Function

```
private  IpInfo GetUserLocationDetailsyByIp(string ip)
    {
        var ipInfo = new IpInfo();
        try
        {
            var info = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://freegeoip.net/json/" + ip);
            ipInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IpInfo>(info);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Exception Handling
        }

        return ipInfo;
    }
```

Calling function with IP value

```
var ipDetails = GetUserCountryByIp("8.8.8.8"); //IP value
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer for people is searching in 2022 :).

You can use [ip3country-dotnet](https://github.com/statsig-io/ip3country-dotnet). It is small library <500KB. This library is using [ip2location](https://lite.ip2location.com/edition-comparison) the lite version, it is totally free!.

Way of usage:
Install `IP3Country`, then write this code

```
// Lookup using ip4 str
var country = CountryLookup.LookupIPStr("123.45.67.8"); // => 'KR'

// Lookup using numeric ip
country = CountryLookup.LookupIPNumber(2066563848); // => 'KR'
```